# embedding html to screen

Tags: jquery, html, text

Well i have `var message`, which has any type of character...

I replace :) with `<img src="..." .../>` and `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id` with `<a href="...">...</a>`

Then I run `$(".chat_message").html(message);`

What must I do to embed anything excepts the html tags I make as html code to screen??

Comment: The question is a little bit wirred for me. It is possible to reduce a whole site to a "script src" tag. If you want to embed a video check dynamic object model (DOM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What must I do to embed anything excepts the html tags I make as html code to screen??

I'm going to assume you want each character in `message` except the ones you replace with HTML tags to show literally on the screen.

```
var messageHTML = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

will put the HTML equivalent of `message` in `messageHTML`*.

Once `messageHTML` contains a string of HTML, you can replace all occurrences of `":)"` safely and correctly since that is just a simple HTML -> HTML conversion.

```
messageHTML = messageHTML.replace(/:\)/g, "<img ...>");
```

Now you can use jQuery's `.html(messageHTML)` to inject `message` with your tags into the DOM.

* - the white-space will differ unless you're embedding in a context with CSS `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap`

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark (your question isn't very clear). This takes in a string, replaces all the HTML tags with ASCII codes, the somewhat weird part is then grabbing that sanitized output and adding the smiley image:

```
var message = $('<p>stuff in <span>here</span> :)</p>').html();
$(".chat_message").text(message);
$(".chat_message").html($('.chat_message').html().replace(/:\)/g, "<img />"));
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5fT5b/1/

Answer (score 0):

The following example handles web-site URLs and non-ASCII characters:

```
var message = "My name is Andy :) - and my fav web-site is http://stackoverflow.com";

//Protect against HTML characters (you might want to add more).
message=message
    .replace("&", "&amp;")
    .replace("<", "&lt;")
    .replace("<", "&gt;");

//Protect against non-ASCII characters.
message=message
    .replace(/[\x80-\xff]/, "*");

//Handle smilies.
message=message
    .replace(":)", '<img src="..." />');

//Handle embedded web-site addresses.  The "$0" bit says to repeat the matched thing.
//The "https?" matches "http" and "https". If you want something smarter then check out
//http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp
message=message
    .replace(/https?:[^ ]+/g, '<a href="$0">$0</a>');

$(".chat_message").html(message);
```

I vaguely remember reading about properly HTML encoding text and that there were a bunch of characters above ASCII 128 that could potentially be used to inject scripting. The [\x80-\xff] bit should protect against those.

Comment: `.replace("<", "&gt;");` is a copy-and-paste error, and even if it were fixed it would still be broken.  `"<<".replace("<", "&gt;") == "&gt;<"` because replace with a string only replaces the *first* occurrence.